# Запуск activity в handler

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь запустить активити в отдельном потоке с промежутком времени,код такой:
И сам вопрос:
все работает,активность запускается,можно ли как  сделать отдельным методом или как,что бы в каждом case не писать  `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {`

```
 arr_imageA[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            playSample(R.raw.click_sound);
                            switch (v.getId())
                            {
                                case R.id.imageView1:
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), a1.class));
                                        }
                                    }, 100);


                                    break;

                                case R.id.imageView2://todo копипаст
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), a2.class));
                                    break;
                                case R.id.imageView3:
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), a3.class));
                                    break;

                            }
                        }



            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

метод

```
public void startActivity(final Context activityContext, final Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(activityContext, activityClass));
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

В вашем коде отличие только в том, что вы запускаете разные активити, значит нужно это часть(разные активити) вынести как параметр для метода. Если посмотреть на объявление конструктора для класса Intent

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

то видим, что вторым параметром является `Class<?> cls`, где `<?>` означает любой тип данных (то есть Class от любого типа данных). Далее выносим этот параметр в наш собственный метод и делаем его таким `Class<? extends Activity> activityClass` где `<? extends Activity>` означает что мы хотим принимать Сlass от любого типа данных, родителем которого является Activity

Ну а затем в case передаем конкретные экземпляры Сlass соответствующих активити

```
startActivity(getActivity(), a1.class); //и так далле
```

так как родителем любой активити является Context, то выше приведенный вызов метода валиден

Comment: если не сложно,опишите принцип работы данного метода,Спасибо

Comment: Добавил описание

Comment: СПАСИБО!БОЛЬШОЕ!